# How to change the Caption property of a button on a subform from a module access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

The problem;

Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method

I'm trying to dynamically load buttons based on the results of a query. I have a recordset setup to index through said results, and set the Captions on the buttons to match each individual result of the query.
This code I initially had attached to the on open event of the subform that contains all the buttons. Each button has a set name. Command 1-15 on the first page, 16-30 on the second, etc. This code worked initially, but I wanted to move it into a module that way I could call it from any of the subforms instead of putting this large codeblock into each subforms on open event (12+).
My first issue was trying to pinpoint the specific button with a variable which I was able to solve below.
 `Forms![001_frm_Home]![Subform01]![Subform02].['uTargetButton'].Caption = Trim(rs!Itemkey)`

I've tried every combination of quotes, setting the .Caption property to a variable and using the variable in the above line. I've seen a few posts on various forums saying this might not be possible for that I may need to define the command button as a command button in this function in order to access the .Caption property.
I'll put the code block below;

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.CursorType = 2 ' needed to set the recordset for updates
    rs.LockType = 2
    rs.Open strsql, con, 1   ' 1 = adOpenKeyset
    
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then ' We found a good number, ok to move on
        rs.MoveFirst
        uButtonNumber = uStartButton
        uCount = 0
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            uButtonNumber = uButtonNumber + 1
            uCount = uCount + 1
            uTargetButton = "Command" & uButtonNumber
                
            Forms![001_frm_Home]![Subform01]![Subform02].['uTargetButton'].Caption = Trim(rs!Itemkey)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else 'No Record
```

Hopefully all that makes sense, let me know if any further info would help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must access the `Form` property of the Subform Control:

```vb
Forms![001_frm_Home]![Subform01].Form!uTargetButton.Caption = "Hello"
```

If you are calling this from the `001_frm_Home` form, you can also write:

```vb
Me![Subform01].Form!uTargetButton.Caption = "Hello"
```

Explanation, when you add a subform to a form, a `Subform` control is added to the parent form. This `Subform` control has a property `Source Object` in the `Data` tab of the Property Sheet. Here you can select a form from a drop-down. The form selected as subform is available programmatically through the `Form` property.

---

It seems that you have subforms nested twice. Then this would be:

```vb
Forms![001_frm_Home]![Subform01].Form![Subform02].Form(uTargetButton).Caption = "x"
```

Okay did not understand that `uTargetButton` was supposed to be a variable name, because you delimited it by single quotes.

You can access a control by a name given as string with `Form(nameAsString)`. The `()` are indexing the controls default collection. You could also write `Form.Controls(nameAsString)`. This is also equivalent to `Form.Controls!theName` or `Form!theName` or `Form![theName]` where `theName` is the name not given as string.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like that either, when I take uTargetButton out of the brackets. 
```Forms![001_frm_Home]![Subform01]![Subform02].Form!uTargetButton.Caption = Trim(rs!Itemkey)```
The above is giving me a '2465' error saying it cant find the uTargetButton field. This was my first issue I ran into but putting uTargetButton as ['uTargetButton'] was what seemed to allow that variable to stick to what it was defined as in the line above.
I may just be in the wrong scope as the button I'm trying to target is two subforms deep in essence.

Comment: Just deleted my previous comment, your latest edit solved it, I appreciate the help greatly thank you!